# Не добавляются элементы в интерфейс List в цикле

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, arraylist, test-automation, testng

1. Не добавляются элементы в интерфейс List в цикле
2. Идея пишет private field "" is never assigned
   Вопрос: не могу понять почему не добавляет в список элементы

package ua.liebherr.pages.OtherPage;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import utils.RandomMinMax;

import java.util.List;

public class LbhVisitedProduct {
public LbhVisitedProduct(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
private WebDriver driver;
private By visitedBlockLocator = By.xpath("*****");
private WebElement visitedBlock;
private By mainMenuItemsLocator = By.xpath("**********");
private List<WebElement> sliderElements;
private List<WebElement> subMenuItems;
private By subMenuItemsLocator = By.xpath("**************");

    public WebElement getVisited(){
        visitedBlock = driver.findElement(visitedBlockLocator);
        visitedBlock.sendKeys("");
        return visitedBlock;
    }

    public void goToRandomProducts(){
        sliderElements = driver.findElements(mainMenuItemsLocator);
        //int RandomItem = RandomMinMax.Go(1,sliderElements.size());
        System.out.println(sliderElements.size());
        sliderElements.get(RandomMinMax.Go(1,sliderElements.size())).click();
        sliderElements.clear();
        System.out.println(sliderElements.size());
        sliderElements = driver.findElements(subMenuItemsLocator);
        System.out.println(sliderElements.size());
        for(WebElement element:sliderElements){
            System.out.println("LOOP");
            if (element.isDisplayed()){
                System.out.println(subMenuItems.size()+"Try add");
                subMenuItems.add(element);
                System.out.println("Add element");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо создать инстанс `subMenuItems`:

`private List<WebElement> subMenuItems = new ArrayList<>();`